# count occourrence in a list

Tags: python, iteration, assert

I'd like to have an advice in order to write the followings line in a better way...

```
# raise exception in case of backendport or frontendport are not valid
assert len([backend_port['backend']['bport'] for backend_port in self.backend if backend_port['backend']['bport'] == '0']) >= 0, 'backend port not valid: BPNVAL'
assert self.port == 0, 'frontend port not valid: FPNVAL'
```

I'd like to know if in the dictionary called backend there are at least 1 port defined '0', and raise an exception in that way.

Thanks!

Comment: The length of a list is always going to be `>= 0`. Did you mean `== 0`? Also, `assert` works the other way round: you assert that the condition is `True`: if it is `False`, you raise an exception. So I'm guessing the second line should be `self.port != 0`.

Answer (score 4):

Let's first fix the `>=0` bug, which is always true for a list:

```
len([backend_port['backend']['bport'] for backend_port in self.backend
     if backend_port['backend']['bport'] == '0']) > 0
```

Then, skip the `len` call:

```
[backend_port['backend']['bport'] for backend_port in self.backend
 if backend_port['backend']['bport'] == '0']
```

This list comprehension is a boolean expression that is true when the list is non-empty. But the entire list is unnecessary, and `any` is both clearer and faster:

```
any(backend_port['backend']['bport'] == '0' for backend_port in self.backend)
```

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what i was searching!